# In jqueryui dialog how to resize buttons

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I have two buttons, "Delete" and "Cancel", inside a dialog. I am using jquery Ui. Googled it but did not get desired solutions. Below is my code. How can I increase or decrease the height and width of the buttons inside the dialog?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 150,
    width: 300,
    buttons: {
      "Delete": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      "Cancel": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you want that the user can resize the buttons or should the browser resize the buttons according to the screen or something

Comment: @Vinc199789: As I am using jquery-ui.css, the buttons are already flexible with the screen size. I want to hard code the height and width of the buttons.

Comment: Yes but should the user be able to resize the buttons with jquery you can easy change the height by using `.height()` and `.width()` but I don't uderstand "I want to hard code the height and width of the buttons.".

Comment: @Vinc199789, by hard code i meant i want to put the height and width by my choice :)

Comment: @Vinc199789: Where i should put  `.height()` and `.width()`

Comment: I finally understand your question and problem. Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386478/how-to-change-the-button-size-in-the-jquery-ui-confirmation-dialog

Comment: @Vinc199789, well the link is good. Can you tell me how I can make the buttons show at the center of the div? I have tried changing in the stylesheet css, but it is not happening.

Comment: select the buttons with css and assign `text-align:center` and `vertical-align:middle`. this should work. your selector I guess: `#dialog-confirm .ui-button-text `

Comment: @Vinc199789: did not get you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b8u8o0g5/1/ for the buttons you need to use the css selector like you can see in a few commends below